# How can I register bloc with get it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to register the bloc so that I can use it in different places. I register the bloc using Get it, but an error is displayed in the console: Object/factory with type StatesBloc is not registered inside GetIt.(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance; Did you forget to register it?)
How to properly register and use a bloc?

```js
final injector = GetIt.instance;

class DependencyInitializer {
  DependencyInitializer._();

  static void initDependencies() {
    injector
    
      //Bloc
      ..registerLazySingleton<StatesBloc>(StatesBloc.new);
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 
  final _bloc = injector<StatesBloc>();
  
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this if you still facing the same problems.

> For the sake of accessing [injector] anywhere you need it.

```
GetIt get injector => GetIt.instance;
```

> Create helper class like you did it before.

```
class DependencyInitializer {
   // Maybe another dependencies need to wait for initializing
   static Future<void> initDependencies() async {

   // Register Bloc dependency
   injector.registerFactory<StatesBloc>(() => StatesBloc());
   }
}
```

From the official documentation of get_it packages, it says that:

> Factory

```
void registerFactory<T>(FactoryFunc<T> func)
```

> You have to pass a factory function func that returns a NEW instance
> of an implementation of T. Each time you call get() you will get a
> new instance returned.

I think you need to use the registerFactory than registerSingleton or registerLazySingleton, because your Bloc will return the new instance when the state was changed.

You need to initialize all of your dependencies inside main function

```
void main() async {
   // If no binding has yet been initialized, 
   // the WidgetsFlutterBinding class is used to create and 
   // initialize one.
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

   // Wait the Service Locator which is using get_it package
   // to finished its initialization setup before launch the app.
   await DependencyInitializer.initDependencies();

   //Start running the application.
   runApp(const HomePage());
}
```

You can use your Bloc instance from get_it, like your previous code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   ....

   return BlocProvider(
    create: (_) => injector.get<StatesBloc>(),
     child: Scaffold(),
  
   ....
```

You can check the full guide of get_it from [official get_it documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)